# How we can possibly transfer a USART signal(3.3v) over 12 meter cable without any driver?

Tags: power-supply, signal, embedded, uart, transmission-line

I have two atmega328p boards working at 3.3v. First boards read a sensor value and send it to the second board through the USART. The two boards have 12 meter distance. The two boards are connected by RJ45 connector and cable. The cable lines are VCC(3.3v), GND, RX, TX. Two boards are powered from the same battery sitting near to the second board. So the first board will get power through the cable.
Important :- The installing environment will have large rpm motors.

Is it possible to transfer the USART signal without any RS232 driver over 12 meter ?

Comment: It's possible but not to be relied upon.

Comment: Can you say why? How to make it reliable to use?

Comment: if you want reliable use a driver.

Comment: Friends, actually we need to do it without driver?.

Comment: Is there any driver works on 3v? If it is, whether it is possible to transfer over 30 feet?

Comment: 3.3V and 30 feet? That is easy with any RS232 tranceiver.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is a second approach. Actually my boss need to implement this without driver. So what problems will have if I go without driver?

Comment: It would be possible to add a more robust receiver (comparator with hysteresis) to the other board. But a better solution would be to fire that boss.

Comment: vishnu m c: If the problem is the 3.3V voltage level, then there are 3.3V transceivers, e.g. from Maxim. They use chargepump to reach RS232 compatible voltages. https://para.maximintegrated.com/en/results.mvp?fam=rs232&793=3.3

Comment: speed?  >100k? 9600?

Answer (score 1):

In a harsh environment you may really need a driver to get reliable results. Large motors may influence the voltages on the cable and cause transmission errors.

So, if your boss is truely an unmoving mountain:

- use a low transmission speed,
- check for errors (USART, CRC),
- re-send (or discard) data if errors occur,
- thouroughly test before you deliver;

Also, if you do this, don't tell your clients it uses RS-232; [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) specifies the physical layer too... Using 0 and 3V3 makes it 'not RS-232'.

Comment: You make it sound as if it is feasible to do this project without transceivers. It is not.

Comment: Lundin: The question is not whether it's feasible, but whether it's possible.

Comment: @G.B. This is an Electrical _Engineering_ site. An engineer always question the requirements and apply critical thinking. If everyone involved is a quack, then indeed they can do whatever they like, until they end up in court for failing to meet safety and EMC regulations.

Comment: @Lundin: I do not find any statement saying that this is going to be a product. And everyone knows that it is possible with RS232 driver. The question is this: "Is it possible to transfer the USART signal without any RS232 driver over 12 meter ?"

Comment: @G.B. Still the same category of questions as "can I rub my cat against the PCB instead of hiring an ESD gun". It's not engineering.

Comment: If I don't have an ESD gun, I'll rub my cat against the PCB before sending it to an ESD lab. For a proof of concept device it is certainly acceptable for me not to use a driver, if it means not having to design and wait for a new PCB. Again: nobody said the question is about a product and nobody said it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

So let me see if I understand your spec:  must use UART, must not use transceivers, must have 12m cable and must drive large motors, which are potentially supplied through the same cable assembly.

I'm sorry if I come across as rude, but whoever came up with this spec is an incompetent quack.

Using UART for long distances is unreliable and completely unprofessional, particularly so if there are motors and other noisy things present in the system. RS-232 would improve the situation somewhat, but it's icky 1960s technology. The professional solution would be to use RS-485 transceivers and a differential signal. These are relatively cheap and easier to use than RS-232 even. Far cheaper than a hopelessly broken product that can't be used for sure. There's standardized pin-outs for RS-485 over RJ-45.

Needless to say, on top of that you need protocol layer safety with CRC and sync words etc.

Additionally, providing a 3V3 from a battery over 12m wire will give you voltage drops, depending on current consumption and wire thickness. That's not very feasible either. Why are you using batteries in the first place, since this seems to be a fixed installation? Why can't you use industry standard 24V with decentralised voltage regulators?

Comment: Can you provide source for "standardized pin-outs for RS-485 over RJ-45"?

Comment: @Rev1.0 Well I thought surely there must be a RJ45 standard for RS-485 like there is for CAN, Ethernet etc... then I did some googling and there's apparently a countless of various trashware pin-outs for these. To the point where I can't even trust usually reliable sources like Siemens, Phoenix etc. Guess you have to dig up the actual EIA 485 standard.

Answer (score -1):

If it's only the RS232 driver that is not allowed, then some ideas:

- LVDS - you need twisted pair cables
- software driven UART transceiver switching 2 pins inverted (on same port) -> transfer through twisted pair cables (as they were differential) -> software driven UART receiver (with error detection logic). This might only work with low baudrates b.c. of uC processing jitter. I don't think it's very reliable.
- worst case: use shielded cables (coax?) with error detection/correction protocols and low speed

Comment: "worst case: use shielded cables (coax?) with error detection/correction protocols and low speed" This doesn't work. I've maintained crap like that, pure UART over a few meters cable in an industrial environment, shielded cables. Sounds good? No, it was completely broken crap. The system would cease to work if a butterfly flipped its wings nearby. CRC won't save you, low speed won't save you. Don't design crap that they would be ashamed of back in the 1960s, simple as that.

Comment: Lundin: I disagree. I've seen SPI working on 1MHz on a 2m+ cable working reliably. But of course only if the impedances are matched, the shielding is correct (every line is a coax) and the grounding is ok. Actually it was a life-time testing equipment for sensors, so it ran for months continuously. Question is, whether it can be made to work with the Atmega boards.

Comment: SPI is a completely different beast - it clocks every bit and you can implement error detection closer to the hardware. UART clocks every 10 bits and it's error detection is next to non-existent.

Comment: At any rate, inventing some non-standard exotic crap system for thousands and thousands of dollars instead of using a $1 industry standard RS-485 transceiver doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In that I agree. But if that's the task then that's the task.